# Controlling bandwith while using GPRS on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bandwidth, mobile-broadband, gprs

I have an issue with my windows 7 machine using a lot of bandwith while connected to the internet. I'm trying to limit the bandwith by using Opera in Turbo mode, but some other program is sucking down content and emptying my GPRS mobile plan.

Is there some way I can control which applications are allowed to use bandwith while on GPRS? Preferable only Opera should be able to use the network.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs like [Comodo Firewall](http://personalfirewall.comodo.com/) can allow you to monitor your internet connection and actively control and limit programs access to internet connections.  At the very least you will be able to see what programs are wasting your bandwidth.

With Comodo you can allow or block pretty much every program that tries to access the internet.

Other [firewall solutions are available](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-firewall.htm), Comodo is just one I've used previously and came to mind with the restrictiveness you might be after.